# Regex for password validation is not working ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: regex, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this regular expression that should work for password like P@ssword1234. However it doesn't seem to be matching. I've used this same regex in Angular and it worked

This is the password criteria below

```
// 10 characters or more
// at least one digit
// at least one uppercase letter
// at least one lowercase letter
// at least one special character 

[DisplayName("Password")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your password.")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]

[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*(),.?"":{}|<>])(?=.*[a - z])(?=.*[A - Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*(),.?"":{}|<>]{10,}$",
 ErrorMessage = "Password must contain at least 10 characters, including at least 1 uppercase letter, at least 1 lowercase letter, at least one number and a special character.")]
```

Comment: Password rules like this make me sad.... Why are you making such arbitrary and unnecessary constraints?  Characters like `£`, `€`, `§`, ... "Don't count", because you didn't think to include them in your arbitrary list of "special" characters.

Comment: For example, this isn't a valid password according to your rules: `Not-A-Valid-Password123!` ... because hyphens aren't included in your list of "valid characters"!! (Why do you even *have* a list of "valid characters"?) Instead of `[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*(),.?"":{}|<>]{10,}$`, why not just put `.{10}`?

Comment: @TomLord thank you for the suggestion. Work on your delivery though

Comment: Sorry if I came across harshly (it's been a long week...) My sentiment, however, is that your original implementation was not merely buggy (which is totally forgivable; you were trying to fix that!), but unprofessional. Only considering 20 characters as "special" is very shortsighted -- you surely must have realised that, but were choosing to copy some bad code from Angular to C# without making it better.

Comment: Moreover, I surely can't be the only person who has stumbled across countless websites with absurd password rules. Such as: "Maximum length 12 characters", "`;` character is *not* allowed", "Cannot contain a common word", "Cannot contain repeating numbers", "Cannot contain any part of your name", ..... --- As professional software engineers, we should be striving to improve the user experience, not impose pointless/arbitrary rules on people. To me, having a long list of characters that are explicitly *not allowed* to be in the password is a really terrible (but painfully common) design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in writing `[a - z]` instead of `[a-z]`. The former actually means "the letter `a`, or any characters between `<space>` and `<space>`, or the letter `z`". In other words, only the characters `a`,   and `z`.

Here is the "fixed" regex:

```
@"^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*(),.?"":{}|<>])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&*(),.?"":{}|<>]{10,}$"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ClZXiF/1)

...However, as mentioned in the comment above, I'd advise against putting such an arbitrary list of "required special characters" in the password. Wouldn't it be better to define this much more loosely, e.g. "Anything that's **not** a letter or number qualifies as being 'special'"?

You could achieve that with something like this:

```
^(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{10,}$
```